# How can I print only one of the inputs from a for i in range loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, input, range

```
x = 64
root = 0

for pwr in range(2,6):
    if x > 1:
        while root <= x:
            root += 1
        
            if root**pwr == x:            
                print('root = ', root, ' and pwr = ', pwr)
        root = 0
    elif x < 0:
        while root >= x:
            root -= 1
        
            if root**pwr == x:            
                print('root = ', root, ' and pwr = ', pwr)
        root = 0
    elif x == 0:
        print('There is no such pair')
        break
```

The inputs I receive are:
root =  8  and pwr =  2
root =  4  and pwr =  3

However, I am only looking to get the highest root answer if available.

So what I want my input to be is only:

root =  8  and pwr =  2

And also vice versa... what should I do if I only want it to display:
root =  4  and pwr =  3

Thanks!

Comment: Well, do things inside the loop happen once, or multiple times? Do you want the `print` to happen once, or multiple times? Therefore, should it happen inside, or outside the loop? Now, the next question is how you figure out what it should print. Here is a hint: try using a variable to remember the *best result seen so far*. Can you see how to use that result after the loop has finished?

Comment: Not sure I fully understand the requirement but it looks as though a *break* after *print()* might be all you need

Comment: @BrutusForcus Yes! That fixed my first issue, but now how do I go about getting it to only print root = 4 and power = 3?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Can you expand on your hint? I cannot think of any variable to represent the best result. I appreciate the first tip it makes a lot more sense now why I was printing multiple values.

Comment: you should keep results `root`, `pwr` in some other variables (ie. `max_root, max_pwr`) and later compare with new `root`, `pwr` and keep old values or replace by new values - and you should print these values only after all calculations. This way you check all values and you get only one result. OR you should keep all results on list and after all calculations filter result which you need and display it.

Comment: "I cannot think of any variable to represent the best result." This doesn't make any sense. You know what a variable is. What you need to do is assign a value to it. You know what `=` does, right? Try to think about the process step by step. Use a real pencil and piece of paper and draw a diagram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create new variables `max_root, max_pwr` and when you calculate `root` then you should check if it is bigger then `max_root` and replace `max_root, max_pwr` or keep older value.

And you should display only after all calculations

```
x = 64
root = 0

max_root = 0
max_pwr = 0

for pwr in range(2,6):
    if x > 1:
        while root <= x:
            root += 1
        
            if root**pwr == x:            
                #print('root = ', root, ' and pwr = ', pwr)
                if root > max_root:
                    max_root = root
                    max_pwr = pwr
        root = 0
    elif x < 0:
        while root >= x:
            root -= 1
        
            if root**pwr == x:            
                #print('root = ', root, ' and pwr = ', pwr)
                if root > max_root:
                    max_root = root
                    max_pwr = pwr

        root = 0
    elif x == 0:
        print('There is no such pair')
        break

# after `for`-loop

print('root = ', max_root, ' and pwr = ', max_pwr)
```

Similar way you can do for other result but you may need `<` instead of `>` in line `root > max_root` and you need to set big `max_root` at start - ie. 99999.

```
x = 64
root = 0

max_root = 99999
max_pwr = 0

for pwr in range(2,6):
    if x > 1:
        while root <= x:
            root += 1
        
            if root**pwr == x:            
                #print('root = ', root, ' and pwr = ', pwr)
                if root < max_root:
                    max_root = root
                    max_pwr = pwr
        root = 0
    elif x < 0:
        while root >= x:
            root -= 1
        
            if root**pwr == x:            
                #print('root = ', root, ' and pwr = ', pwr)
                if root < max_root:
                    max_root = root
                    max_pwr = pwr

        root = 0
    elif x == 0:
        print('There is no such pair')
        break

# after `for`-loop

print('root = ', max_root, ' and pwr = ', max_pwr)
```

---

Other method to create list for all results and after calculations filter results and display only results which you need.

```
x = 64
root = 0

all_results = []

for pwr in range(2,6):
    if x > 1:
        while root <= x:
            root += 1
        
            if root**pwr == x:            
                #print('root = ', root, ' and pwr = ', pwr)
                all_results.append( [root, pwr] )
        root = 0
    elif x < 0:
        while root >= x:
            root -= 1
        
            if root**pwr == x:            
                #print('root = ', root, ' and pwr = ', pwr)
                all_results.append( [root, pwr] )
        root = 0
    elif x == 0:
        print('There is no such pair')
        break

# after `for`-loop

#print(all_results)

max_result = max(all_results, key=lambda x:x[0])
max_root, max_pwr = max_result
print('MAX: root = ', max_root, ' and pwr = ', max_pwr)

min_result = min(all_results, key=lambda x:x[0])
min_root, min_pwr = min_result
print('MIN: root = ', min_root, ' and pwr = ', min_pwr)
```